# How to structure Git repo for multi-tier architecture

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

We have what I believe is a typical architecture these days, comprising an iOS client, Android client, and a J2EE backend. These look like this in the file system:

- myProject

  - Code

    - client_iOS
    - client_android
    - server_J2EE
    - db
  - Creative
  - Other

While I was working on my own and coding the entire stack, I had everything in the same git repo with folder `.git` under `<myProject>`. That was great because I could track changes per 'feature' across the entire stack. For example fixing a bug might required changes on server + iOS files, so such changes had to be tracked in unison.

However now that the team is about to expand, I need to restrict access across these layers to the relevant teams. For example, the backend team should not be able to access iOS files, and vice versa. Ideally I'd like git (or a git host) to have authorization on a per-folder basis, which would solve the problem nicely. But I haven't seen that feature anywhere.

If I split the code in separate repositories, we will no longer be able to track changes in synchrony. Rolling back to previous versions as those independent repos evolve asynchronously over time, will become a real mess.

I read up on git submodules and it doesn't look like the use case is a good fit. They also have a lot of overhead and room for errors, from a human workload perspective. It seems like a typical scenario, I'd like to hear how others have dealt with this problem.

Answer (score 2):

This is a common project growth challenge. The most common solution is multiple repositories with shared or independent release names that tie them together; see for example the [Spring Framework](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework) project's relationship to the [Spring Boot](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot) project.

**Note**: my preference is make these independent repositories, but accessible to all developers -- with an emphasis on making the entire development cycle as quick as possible.

Comment: We tried that in some test projects, what ends up happening over time is what I describe in my OP as something we are trying to avoid. What is great about git goes away and we have to now deal with a manual process of keeping things synced. Thanks for the input but we were hoping for a more 'Git-y' way of doing it.